# Is it possible to build some Arduino projects using Google"Android Accessory Development Kit" for GoogleTV applications?

Tags: android, arduino, google-tv, adk

I want to start a project wich will work on GoogleTV, like an Arduino/Picpus board with some features, and I want to know if it's possible to use Google "Android Accessory Development Kit" to build it,  and connect these boards with the "Android/GoogleTV" world. 
Does anyone is "experimented" in this kind of work, or may be know any projetcs like that ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get the ADK working with the various Google TV devices and it does not work. The  current Google TV devices have limited support for USB devices.

Comment: Hi Leon, do you think it's only a hardware problem ?

Comment: Its not clear to me what is missing. Here is the feature request: https://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=16&q=Type%3DEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Summary

Comment: As I understand it, not having tried it, is that GoogleTV's are USB masters, where phones are USB clients.  ADK turns things a bit on their head - the device being controlled is a USB Master not client.  Google TV supports HID and mass storage USB devices.

Comment: Hi LES, do you think that we can use this ADK to connect dedicated Wifi devices to the GoogleTV box ?

Comment: Don't know about WiFi, but most ARM based GoogleTV's have Bluetooth, you should be able to get ADT 2.0 to work w/ Bluetooth.